# Count returns different results for similar set of tables, why?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, firebird-3.0

I need to count the number of times product_rec_id matches, is assigned, two or more vendor's names.

For example, when a user enters *sarsa* and *bobbie25* I should get a value count of 1 from the example vendors' table below.

This is what I have and the strange thing, to me, is that these two methods work on the keywords' tables but not with the vendors' tables, the Count always returns a value of 0. The tables are practically similar, what could be the problem?

```
SELECT
  Count(distinct product_rec_id)
FROM
  vendors
  INNER JOIN vendors_products ON vendors_products.vendor_rec_id = vendors.vendor_rec_id
WHERE
  (vendors.name LIKE '%sarsa%') AND
  (vendors.name LIKE '%bobbie25%')
```

For Firebird 3 I change `Then 1` to `Then True`.

```
SELECT
  Count((CASE
    WHEN vendors.name LIKE '%sarsa%'
    THEN 1
  END) AND (CASE
    WHEN vendors.name LIKE '%bobbie25%'
    THEN 1
  END)) AS TRows
FROM
  vendors
  INNER JOIN vendors_products ON vendors_products.vendor_rec_id = vendors.vendor_rec_id
WHERE
  (vendors.name LIKE '%sarsa%' OR
    vendors.name LIKE '%bobbie25%')
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE vendors (
    vendor_rec_id     INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    company_broker_id INTEGER       NOT NULL,
    name              VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    vendor_id         VARCHAR (50),
    store_url         VARCHAR (255),
    website_url       VARCHAR (255) 
);

CREATE TABLE vendors_products (
    product_rec_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    vendor_rec_id  INTEGER
);
```

-

```
vendors' table data:
        60 2 bobbie25 73658 http://www.somewebsite.com/ http://www.somewebsite.com/
        43 2 sarsa    61688 http://www.somewebsite.com/ http://www.somewebsite.com/
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE keywords (
    keyword_rec_id INTEGER      PRIMARY KEYNOT NULL,
    keyword        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    chart          INTEGER      NOT NULL
                                DEFAULT 0
);
CREATE TABLE keywords_products (
    keyword_rec_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_rec_id INTEGER
);
```

The vendor_rec_id and name fields in *vendors* tables look like this, here's an example of the *vendors* table (there are never any null values):

```
vendor_rec_id  name
--------------  -----------
60              bobbie25
43              sarsa
87              johnf
```

The vendor_rec_id and product_rec_id in *vendors_products* tables looks like this (one vendor name can be assigned to many products) (there are never any null values):

```
vendor_rec_id  product_rec_id
--------------  --------------
43              1
60              1
43              2
87              3
```

Comment: Are vendor.names supposed to be like `'%sarsa%' AND '%bobbie25%'` at the same time in your first query? It can be either of 1 and the count will always be 0.

Comment: So why is it working with the keywords' tables without fault? It always counts as I expect.

Comment: What is the content of the table `vendors`, and please be more explicit what works and what doesn't. And what you expect **and why**. As mentioned on your previous question, your whole construction with usage of `count(case ... and case ...)` does not make a lot of sense, but we can't suggest an alternative as it is really unclear what you are really trying to do. Also in the text you mention _"when a user enters melee and scifi"_, but your example filters on vendor names. Please make your question self-consistent.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: The problem is that your condition as presented will only count rows where **both** conditions are true **in the same row**, and that will never be the case. Why isn't the count distinct good enough?

Comment: That is what I have been explaining, especially to  Arioch 'The. I clearly stated that from the first time I asked my question. The keywords/names are in separate rows. He kept pushing me to do the count(1) with a Where, so I also tried it. The distinct is not good enough because it counts even if only one matches, I can do that operation with a simple OR.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally managed to put together. This works without issues.

Now when a user enters more than one keyword and wants to pull records matching all the keywords entered I can use this one to fetch the record count and the records themselves (without the Count(*) Select).

I am sure there is a better way to get this done, but this is what my limited experience with SQL gets me.

```
Select Count(*) As TRows From
(Select
  vendors_products.product_rec_id
From
  vendors_products
  Inner Join vendors On vendors_products.vendor_rec_id = vendors.vendor_rec_id
Where
  (Lower(vendors.name) Like '%sarsa%' OR
    Lower(vendors.name) Like '%bobbie25%')
Group By
  vendors_products.product_rec_id
Having
  Sum(Case
    When lower(vendors.name) Like '%sarsa%'
    Then 1
    Else 0
  End) > 0 And
  Sum(Case
    When lower(vendors.name) Like '%bobbie25%'
    Then 1
    Else 0
  End) > 0
) MyCountResults
```

Comment: You could consider using a single `sum(case when lower(vendors.name) Like '%sarsa%' then 1 when lower(vendors.name) Like '%bobbie25%' then 1 else 0 end) >= 2`; probably won't be a big difference though.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to select all products where there is an entry in `vendors_products` with a given vendor name.

Assuming a table `products` with a column `product_id`, you can do this with

1. Using an `exists` for each vendor you want to check:

   ```
   with product_by_vendor as (
       select vp.product_rec_id, v.name
       from vendors v
       inner join vendors_products vp on v.vendor_rec_id = vp.vendor_rec_id
   )
   select count(*)
   from products p
   where exists (
       select * 
       from product_by_vendor 
       where product_rec_id = p.product_id
       and name like '%sarsa%')
   and exists (
       select * 
       from product_by_vendor 
       where product_rec_id = p.product_id
       and name like '%bobbie25%')
   ```
2. An `inner join` for each vendor you want to check:

   ```
   with product_by_vendor as (
       select vp.product_rec_id, v.name
       from vendors v
       inner join vendors_products vp on v.vendor_rec_id = vp.vendor_rec_id
   )
   select count(*)
   from products p
   inner join product_by_vendor pv1 
       on pv1.product_rec_id = p.product_id and pv1.name like '%sarsa%'
   inner join product_by_vendor pv2 
       on pv2.product_rec_id = p.product_id and pv2.name like '%bobbie25%'
   ```
3. Slightly more obscure (and Firebird specific) using a `cross join` and the `ALL` predicate:

   ```
   with product_by_vendor as (
       select vp.product_rec_id, v.name, v.vendor_rec_id
       from vendors v
       inner join vendors_products vp on v.vendor_rec_id = vp.vendor_rec_id
   ),
   vendors_x_products as (
       select p.product_id, v.name, v.vendor_rec_id
       from products p
       cross join vendors v
   )
   select count(*)
   from products p
   where p.product_id = all (
       select pv.product_rec_id 
       from vendors_x_products vp
       left join product_by_vendor pv
           on vp.product_id = pv.product_rec_id and vp.vendor_rec_id = pv.vendor_rec_id
       where vp.product_id = p.product_id
       and (vp.name like '%sarsa%' or vp.name like '%bobbie25%')
   )
   ```

I'm convinced there might be an easier way, but I just can't think of it right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and helping me. I will study these. However, I did several tests and I noticed that these do a lot more fetches than the solution I put together. The last one goes into the hundreds of thousands. Of course, they are done on the indexes more than my solution, but my solution does about 500 in this case. Is this because my solution is using Group By and doing more in memory?

Comment: @nDelphi That last one is likely not efficient when there are lot of records given its use of `cross join`. It is hard to say if more fetches is good or bad, as the value will depend on whether or not pages are in cached in memory or not (you may want to execute queries multiple times to see how the values change).